# ggplot2 / plotnine: How to plot grouped chart for a melted df?

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I subset and melt an Airbnb dataset and try to plot a grouped chart:

```
from plotnine import *

airbnb_melted = pd.melt(airbnb_newcomers, id_vars =['host_id'], value_vars =['host_identity_verified', 'host_is_superhost']) 
print(airbnb_melted)
```

The melted dataset looks like:

[image]

I know my following code is wrong, and the output of the plot is not what I want but it is closest to my idea:

```
ggplot(airbnb_melted, aes(x='variable', y='value')) +\
        geom_bar(stat = 'sum', position=position_dodge())
```

I have searched online and found lots of plot examples with `y` as numerical variable and `stat='count'` that could be used. However, `y` here is categorical and it shows error `PlotnineError: 'stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic'`

How could I plot a grouped bar chart similar to the following format? The orange words are what I have added as indication. Thank you.

[image]

Updates on Jan.20, 2020: Thanks to @StupidWolf help, the coding works as follows:

```
airbnb_host_count = airbnb_melted.replace(np.NaN, 'NA').groupby(['value', 'variable']).count().reset_index()
```

[image]

## 'host_id' actually indicates counts here:

```
ggplot(airbnb_host_count, aes(x='variable', y='host_id', fill='value')) +\ 
    geom_bar(stat='sum', position=position.dodge())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this:

from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(99)
airbnb_melted = pd.DataFrame(
    {'host_id':np.arange(20),
     'variable': np.repeat(['host_identity_verified','host_is_superhost'],[10,10]) ,
     'value' : random.choices(['t','f','NA'],k=20)
    })
```

I do not have your dataframe, so check what exactly is the NA value, and replace it like this, for example if it is NaN

```
airbnb_melted = airbnb_melted.replace(np.NaN,'NA')
```

We can check the counts:

```
airbnb_melted.groupby(['value','variable']).count()

value   variable    
NA  host_identity_verified  3
host_is_superhost   2
f   host_identity_verified  3
host_is_superhost   6
t   host_identity_verified  4
host_is_superhost   2
```

Now we plot, you set fill = 'value' and do not set 'stat', because the default is 'count' which tallies your t, f and NA:

```
ggplot(airbnb_melted, aes(x='variable', fill='value')) +\
        geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, StupidWolf, and I am sorry I respond you late. I think the ```NA``` data you simulated is actually a string rather than a null value. When I used your coding in my data, the null value was not countable, and it showed ```TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'", 'occurred at index fill')```. Is there any alternative way? I don't want to delete the missing value if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I see. let me try to replace the NA. But what is the actual value you have? Because in python there's no NA, it is NaN I guess?

Comment: HI SupidWolf, I think I figure it out: ```ggplot(airbnb_melted, aes(x='variable',y='host_id', fill = 'value)) + geom_bar(stat = 'sum', position=position_dodge())```. I'll show you the screen shot.

Comment: Do this, airbnb_melted.replace(np.NaN,'NA').groupby(['value','variable']).count()